# Как отключить отправку почты с Debian?

Tags: debian, sendmail, exim4

Нужно полностью временно приостановить отправку почты с сервера на Debian 9.

К сожалению, не сильно разбираюсь в этом вопросе, однако понимаю, что этим занимается пакет типа exim4 или sendmail или что-то еще.

Подскажите, как можно определить, какой пакет на данный момент занимается отправкой почты и как его остановить/отключить.

Наугад попробовал **service exim4 stop**, ошибок не вызвало, почта как-будто не уходит, но она через раз уходила и до этого (может, где-то в очереди).

Если это не отработало, у меня могут тысячи писем улететь спамом, чего не хотелось бы допустить.

Comment: _почта как-будто не уходит, но она через раз уходила и до этого_ - а как вы вообще определяли, что что-то куда-то уходило с этого Дебиана?

Comment: mail -s "Hello World" test@test.test - эта команда отправляет письмо на "test@test.test". Кстати, после "# service exim stop" письма таки отправляются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

принятый в *debian gnu/linux* путь «отключения» функциональности программы — удаление пакета, содержащего эту программу. для возобновления функциональности достаточно будет снова установить этот пакет: все настройки останутся «на месте» (если вы их, конечно, не удалите).

посмотрите, на что указывает символическая ссылка `/usr/sbin/sendmail`:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

это будет файл, содержащий ту программу, которая **принимает** сообщения.

в какой пакет входит файл, можно узнать у программы *dpkg*:

```
$ dpkg -S /путь/к/файлу
```

можно сразу объединить две предыдущие команды в одну:

```
$ dpkg -S $(readlink -f /usr/sbin/sendmail)
```

пример вывода:

```
exim4-daemon-light: /usr/sbin/exim4
```

имя пакета — всё, что до двоеточия, т.е., в данном случае — `exim4-daemon-light`.

получив таким образом имя пакета, удалите его:

```
$ sudo apt remove имя.пакета
```

используйте именно команду `remove`, не `purge`, если хотите сохранить существующие настройки.

Comment: Выполнил команду "dpkg -S $(readlink -f /usr/sbin/sendmail)", результат: "exim4-daemon-light: /usr/sbin/exim4", далее "apt remove exim4", далее "mail -s "Hello World" test@test.test" - письма все-равно приходят на ящик test@test.test. Значит, не exim4 отвечает за отправку писем? Тогда что?

Comment: имя пакета — всё, что до двоеточия, в вашем случае: `exim4-daemon-light`

Comment: Спасибо большое!